# Strange GLib error in pkg-config result

Tags: pkg-config

Ubuntu 18.04 fresh installed.

```
$ pkg-config --list-all 2>&1 | grep -A2 -B2 GLib

(pkg-config:31662): GLib-CRITICAL **: 06:08:21.279: g_string_insert_len: assertion 'len == 0 || val != NULL' failed
```

What the hell is this? Is this something we need to fix?
It happens every time I use pkg-config

I had some GLib error during installation already. But system is somehow usable. More like a GLib problem. How can we fix this? And where is the problem actually?

update according @N0rbert

```
#dpkg --verify
```

Does not yield any related file change, only some common gnome tweaking xml and conf files.
Install the `libglib2.0-dev` does not help either. Same error pop up after `pkg-config --list-all`
Reinstall with the `--reinstall libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-data` does not help either. Well the find is the same as the repo one, so I do not expect this will change anything.

Comment: Looks like a bug in pkg-config

Comment: @Elias more like a GLib bug?

Answer (score 1):

## 1. Check system integrity

I do not see **`GLib-CRITICAL` messages** on my systems, so if unsure, then reinstall related packages with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-data
```

If problem persists, then check system integrity with:

```
sudo dpkg --verify
```

or debsums:

```
sudo apt-get install debsums
sudo debsums --all --changed
```

and reinstall packages with possible damaged/missed/changed files.

## 2. Install packages with `*.pc` files

About `*.pc` files. If you visit search on https://packages.ubuntu.com and [evaluate search for `*.pc` files inside packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=glib%20.pc) you will see the long list of related packages and files:

> [image: glib .pc s]

So you need to install some related dev-packages.

At least one `libglib2.0-dev` with `glib-2.0.pc`:

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
```

and you will get something like:

> ```
> $ pkg-config --list-all | grep -A2 -B2 GLib
> iso-codes                      iso-codes - ISO country, language, script and currency codes and translations
> caja-python                    Caja-Python - Caja-Python Components
> gobject-2.0                    GObject - GLib Type, Object, Parameter and Signal Library
> gmodule-export-2.0             GModule - Dynamic module loader for GLib
> libpcreposix                   libpcreposix - PCREPosix - Posix compatible interface to libpcre
> geoclue-2.0                    Geoclue - The Geoinformation Service
> --
> adwaita-icon-theme             gnome-icon-theme - A collection of icons used as the basis for GNOME themes
> libpcre                        libpcre - PCRE - Perl compatible regular expressions C library with 8 bit character support
> glib-2.0                       GLib - C Utility Library
> mate-keybindings               mate-keybindings - Keybindings configuration for MATE applications
> gmodule-2.0                    GModule - Dynamic module loader for GLib
> gnome-system-tools             gst - Gnome System Tools
> gthread-2.0                    GThread - Thread support for GLib
> caja-sendto                    caja-sendto - Extend caja-sendto through plugins
> xbitmaps                       X bitmaps - Bitmaps that are shared between X applications
> --
> libpcre32                      libpcre32 - PCRE - Perl compatible regular expressions C library with 32 bit character support
> xkeyboard-config               XKeyboardConfig - X Keyboard configuration data
> gmodule-no-export-2.0          GModule - Dynamic module loader for GLib
> xkbcomp                        xkbcomp - XKB keymap compiler
> ```

(tested on clean Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS virtual machine)

---

Note: Debian and Ubuntu are not source-based GNU/Linux distributions, i.e. they are not Gentoo or Funtoo. For latter it is expected to have includes and development packages and tools preinstalled, but for Debian it is not expected.

Comment: In theory, if no other dev repo want this GLib pc info, pkg-config shouldn't even bother to check right? There must be some other packages installed some pc which leads to request this info, but in the mean time fail to make dependencies on it?